# Sugar OS on Raspberry Pi analog sound output

Tags: audio

I'm able to get analog output working on official RPI distro raspbian, but the same procedure fails if using Sugar OS (OLPC). I'm also using berryboot to load the desired image.

Kernel I'm using (I think that berryboot provided this kernel):

```
[olpc@xo-0e-f1-6b ~]$ uname -a
Linux xo-0e-f1-6b.localdomain 3.6.11-rpi-aufs #1 PREEMPT Sun Dec 30 22:31:28 CET 2012 armv6l armv6l armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Which is the same kernel that get loaded if I boot latest raspbian image (correct me if I'm wrong).

In raspbian this commands send sound to analog output:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
aplay Front_Center.wav
```

Under Sugar OS the "sudo amixer cset numid=3 1" fails to set the value.

```
[olpc@xo-0e-f1-6b ~]$ sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
  : values=1
[olpc@xo-0e-f1-6b ~]$ sudo amixer cset numid=3 
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
  : values=0
```

I'm using the same configuration for ALSA as on raspbian:

```
[olpc@xo-0e-f1-6b ~]$ cat /etc/asound.
asound.conf       asound.conf-orig  asound.state      
[olpc@xo-0e-f1-6b ~]$ cat /etc/asound.conf
#
# Place your global alsa-lib configuration here...
#
pcm.mmap0 {
 type mmap_emul;
 slave {
  pcm "hw:0,0";
 }
}

pcm.!default {
 type plug;
 slave {
  pcm mmap0;
 }
}
```

I've noticed that PulseAudio is not available on Sugar OS for RPI (it is Fedora 14 based), but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Thanks!